# Fixing options after switching to another desktop environment

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, settings, bug-reporting

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) and recently installed **`xubuntu-desktop`** environment.

After switching to Xubuntu , There are some option not working like:

[image: screen1]

**Here following not works:**

- About This Computer
- System Settings
- Logout

Hence, It is required to fix for **Xubuntu Desktop** after switching from default Ubuntu (Ex. `unity-control-center` replace with `xfce4-settings-manager`)

**When I click on above options nothing do! so it should removed/replace (indicator) or fixed options.**

Comment: Can you make more clear what your actual question is?

Comment: That's not the usual menu for Xubuntu as xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin looks radically different than that.  Did you log out to change your session to Xubuntu from Ubuntu?  What else did you do in installing the xubuntu-desktop metapackage?

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat Yes I already log out and swtiched to xubuntu. I've installed only meta package `xubuntu-desktop` by `apt-get`.

Comment: Same issue here after running [these commands](http://pastebin.de/raw/?id=3397), as suggested on [Turn Ubuntu 14.04 into Xubuntu 14.04](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative). Well, the `logout` link works for me. Never trust things that have "easy" in their URL.